# Infill NAs with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, multi-index

I have a timeseries dataframe as follows;

```
            Volume
1992-04-01  357.073
1992-04-02  341.931
1992-04-03  318.777
1992-04-04  312.494
1992-04-05  270.837
.
.
.
2002-12-31  283.78
```

Some of the data has gaps and I would like to fill these gaps with the '10 year normal';

I can generate the normal by the following;

```
df_norm = df.groupby(by=[df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
```

which returns;

```
        Volume
1       337.1108
2       362.6250
3   1    354.4670
4       364.3080
5       374.0428
```

and then I trying to fillna() of df with df_norm but struggling to get it right;

This isn't working as the indexing is different..

```
df  = df.asfreq('d')
df  = df.set_index(df.index.day).fillna(df_fut).set_index(df.index)
```

Is there a way around this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is df_fut?
Do you want to fill the nan with the 10 year average or the average of the year the nan is in?

Comment: df_fut is the 10 year average of that specific day. And yes, the former is correct - I want to fill the nan with the 10 year average. For example if 01/03/1994 was missing it would be infilled with the average of every other 01/03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['Volume'] = df['Volume'].fillna(df.groupby(by=[df.index.month & df.index.day])['Volume'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Unfortunately this is actually failing, with the error "ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length".. do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Ah, its because the NaNs are causing the the lengths to be different. Perhaps there is a way of making a new dataframe with the averages and then infilling the old dataframe's NaNs with the new dataframe... tricky with indexing though